# Subequation and Text

Tags: math-mode, equations, subequations

Please,

I would like to know how I can to do this:

Example:

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

x^2 + x = 1   (1.1)

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

x*(x+1) = 1   (1.2)

I need to know how I can insert a text between a subequations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, inserting text between two subequations does not require anything special:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

First a ``normal'' equation:
\begin{equation}
    (a+b)(a-b) =  a^{2}-b^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}

Now two related equations: the first one is
\begin{equation}
    (a+b)^{2} = a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}
\end{equation}
And here is the second one:
\begin{equation}
    (a-b)^{2} = a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Are you sure that this is indeed your problem?